# Why is const word not used with ostream object in overloading << operator?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, ostream

The prototype of operator function to overload << operator is:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const className&);
```

I am a newbee so it would be appreciated if it could get explained with simple examples. Thanks

Comment: Where would you want to use `const`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This was asked earlier, the OP wants to write `friend const ostream& operator<<(const ostream&, const className&);` so that can pass temporary `ostream` objects to `operator<<` I did try to explain the reason, though obviously not very well.

Comment: @joh do feel free to mark this as a duplicate

Comment: @＿Static＿assert No it's not a duplicate. The issue came up as an aside to a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The act of writing to an object of type `ostream` can change its state. For instance, could set the fail bit or any other fail state. For that reason, the function parameter is a reference to non-const.

Comment: Not to mention that conceptually writing to a stream is not const, since it changes the environment, such as the file position for an fstream.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you write

```
foo f;
std::cout << f;
```

you ignore the returned value. Remember that calling operators is similar to calling methods and the same line can be written as:

```
operator<<(std::cout,f);
```

For the argument type, consider that writing something to a stream does modify internal state of the stream. Hence, `operator<<` takes a non-const reference. You cannot pass a `const` object/reference, because a constant stream would not allow anything to be inserted.

Now chaining:

```
foo f,g;
std::cout << f << g;
```

same as

```
operator<<( operator<<( std::cout,f) , g);
            ------------------------
                     |
                     v
             returns non-const ref
```

If `operator<<` would return a constant reference you could not chain it.